# it's possible divide two different sounds with web audio API(headphones and spaekers)?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I would like create a mixer effect with web Audio Api.
Let out a sound from speaker and a different sound from the headphone.

Comment: Well, that's what you want. Now describe in detail the specific issue you are facing when trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can connect to is the destination property of the AudioContext, and from there it's up to the audio hardware to where it will output. So in other terms, unfortunately no, you can't control which output the sound will play on from within Web Audio.